# How do I change the version of Wordnet I am using with nltk?

Tags: nltk, wordnet

I want to use Wordnet 1.6 with nltk for research purposes.
However the version I have is wordnet 3.0

```
wn.get_version()
u'3.0'
```

Is there a way for me to change the version or import another version?

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet_1.6 #?
```

Comment: Using Numpy Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22609472/1168680