# nltk - still old version after upgrading

Tags: python-2.7, pip, nltk

I am trying to install the latest version of nltk. I used `pip` and in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` I get

```
>>> import nltk ; nltk.__version__
'3.1'
```

but in my project directory I get

```
>>> import nltk ; nltk.__version__
'2.0b9'
```

How can I change it to use nltk 3.1?

Comment: Not sure what your project directory is, but are you certain you are using Python 2.7 over there? `sys.version` will make sure of that.

Comment: @scozy `sys.version` - 2.7.6

Comment: I would guess then you have other versions of NLTK installed and available to Python 2.7. I'm not an expert but I think they could hide in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` or `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, or `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7`. Maybe take a look in those places. If you find another version, either remove it or take a look at [various suggestions in this other question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832722/python-select-one-of-multiple-installed-module-versions)