# After updating python, do i have to install modules again?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, importerror

I updated python (from 3.5 to 3.6) and notice that all modules i installed for 3.5 are now no more available for importing in 3.6.

When i try to import PIL in 3.6 for example there is:

```
>>> import PIL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import PIL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
>>>
```

How can i use modules in 3.5 which i imported while in version 3.5? 
Do i have to change some path after updating python or install the modules again every time i update?

Comment: have u tried updating ur pip?

Comment: `pip install pillow`if you have it reinstall

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832722/python-select-one-of-multiple-installed-module-versions?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: You might want to update your question with information about how exactly you installed these libraries and perhaps which platform you're on. But yes, typically, libraries go in a directory whose name includes the Python version number.

Comment: thanks for answering, i reinstalled pillow and it worked. i just wanted to know if this is the usual way to handle modules after upgrades. so this means after every python update i have to manually reinstall every module?

Comment: Yes, it is normal to have to install modules again after changing Python versions. You're not actually updating to a new version of Python, you're installing a new version, so it doesn't know about any of your existing modules. Many of us use package managers to help ease things like this.