# change version requests module by Python

Tags: python, request

please help.

I have install two version of "requests" module by Python. 
And in result i have version 2.2.1  and 2.7.0

But by default I get

```
python2 -c 'import requests; print requests.__version__'
2.2.1
```

How to change to 2.2.7?

Comment: can you please provide what OS, you are on?

Comment: yes sure, Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force python to use an older version of module (than what I have installed now)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445167/force-python-to-use-an-older-version-of-module-than-what-i-have-installed-now)

Comment: Meaby I do somethings wrong?

Comment: >>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.require("requests=2.2.7")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

Answer (score 0):

you can locate your python in this path :`usr/bin/python`. In your case you will have 2 versions `2.2` `2.7`.

While executing python code for `2.2', do this :

`usr/bin/python2.2 code.py` - this will use `2.2`. Do the same for `2.7`

Comment: yes I find it, but what i must do? remove 2.2 version?

Comment: your question was to run the python file in version `2.7`, and the solution to that is given above. if you want to remove `2.2` you can `yum remove usr/bin/python2.2`, and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks, but i again have trouble, i change it but after run script i again have error : AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'is_redirect'
And version agani changed to 2.2.1