# How to configure ChromeDriver to initiate Chrome browser in Headless mode through Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless, browser-options

I'm working on a python script to web-scrape and have gone down the path of using Chromedriver as one of the packages. I would like this to operate in the background without any pop-up windows. I'm using the option 'headless' on chromedriver and it seems to do the job in terms of not showing the browser window, however, I still see the .exe file running. See the screenshot of what I'm talking about. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unkR3.jpg)

This is the code I am using to initiate ChromeDriver:

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["ignore-certificate-errors"])
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=0x0')
chrome_driver_path = "C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe"
```

Things I've tried to do is alter the window size in the options to 0x0 but I'm not sure that did anything as the .exe file still popped up.

Any ideas of how I can do this?

I am using Python 2.7 FYI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Selenium with Headless Chrome Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657215/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome-webdriver)

Comment: @Basj This question is an year older than the question you linked. If anything, the linked question would be a possible duplicate of this.

Comment: I know its a bad idea to like reply to question which is 4 years old. but i see nobody actually solving issue of being shown. If the platform is windows you can do: `import win32gui` and `import win32.lib.win32con as win32con` and in the code include something like `Hwnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(None,None,None,chrome_driver_path)` and then `win32gui.ShowWindow(Hwnd,win32con.SW_HIDE)` later if you want to show it again, you need to `win32gui.ShowWindow(Hwnd,win32con.SW_SHOW)` The code will completely hide the window. only viewable through programs such as task manager running in background

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So after correcting my code to:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["ignore-certificate-errors"])
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_driver_path = "C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe"
```

The .exe file still came up when running the script. Although this did get rid of some extra output telling me "Failed to launch GPU process".

What ended up working is running my Python script using a .bat file

So basically,

1. Save python script if a folder
2. Open text editor, and dump the following code (edit to your script of course)

   c:\python27\python.exe c:\SampleFolder\ThisIsMyScript.py %*
3. Save the .txt file and change the extension to .bat
4. Double click this to run the file

So this just opened the script in Command Prompt and ChromeDriver seems to be operating within this window without popping out to the front of my screen and thus solving the problem.

Answer (score 205):

It should look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # Last I checked this was necessary.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=options)
```

This works for me using Python 3.6, I'm sure it'll work for 2.7 too.

**Update 2018-10-26**: These days you can just do this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
```

**Update 2023-05-22**: Chrome’s Headless mode got an upgrade and now both headless and headful modes have been unified under the same implementation. See https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
```

To try the new Headless mode, pass the `--headless=new` command-line flag:

```
chrome --headless=new
```

For now, the old Headless mode is still available via:

```
chrome --headless=old
```

Currently, passing the `--headless` command line flag without an explicit value still activates the old Headless mode — but we plan to change this default to new Headless over time.

Comment: Thanks! This unfortunately didn't solve the issue. I have posted my answer to what did though. Appreciate your help

Comment: Latest update works when replacing:
options = Options() 
with 
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

Comment: Update: kwarg `chrome_options` for Chrome is deprecated in favour of `options`

Comment: The solution does not work when the website has javascript. I added `options.add_argument('user-agent=fake-useragent')` and it worked.

Comment: ``options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')`` is not necessary.

Comment: do you know why headless is not working on my case even update to new? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78093600/option-add-argument-headless-new-doesnt-work-for-chrome-122-when-scrap-kay

Answer (score 97):

### Answer update of *13-October-2018*

To initiate a [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) *browsing context* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091121/why-doesnt-chromedriver-require-chrome-or-chromium/51096327#51096327) now you can just set the [`--headless`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) property to **`true`** through an instance of `Options()` class as follows:

- Effective code block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.headless = True
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://google.com/")
  print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")
  driver.quit()
  ```

---

### Answer update of *23-April-2018*

Invoking [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) in [headless](/questions/tagged/headless) mode programmatically have become much easier with the availability of the method [**`set_headless(headless=True)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options.set_headless) as follows :

- Documentation :

  ```
  set_headless(headless=True)
      Sets the headless argument

      Args:
          headless: boolean value indicating to set the headless option
  ```
- Sample Code :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.set_headless(headless=True)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://google.com/")
  print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")
  driver.quit()
  ```

> **Note** : [`--disable-gpu`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143413/errorgpu-process-transport-factory-cc1007-lost-ui-shared-context-while-init/50148698#50148698) argument is implemented internally.

---

### Original Answer of *Mar 30 '2018*

While working with *Selenium Client 3.11.x*, *ChromeDriver v2.38* and *Google Chrome v65.0.3325.181* in **Headless** mode you have to consider the following points :

- You need to add the argument **`--headless`** to invoke Chrome in headless mode.
- For *Windows OS systems* you need to add the argument **`--disable-gpu`**
- As per [Headless: make --disable-gpu flag unnecessary](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737678) `--disable-gpu` flag is not required on *Linux Systems* and *MacOS*.
- As per [SwiftShader fails an assert on Windows in headless mode](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=729961) `--disable-gpu` flag will become unnecessary on *Windows Systems* too.
- Argument **`start-maximized`** is required for a maximized **Viewport**.
- Here is the link to details about [**Viewport**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).
- You may require to add the argument **`--no-sandbox`** to bypass the OS security model.
- Effective [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) code block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("--headless") # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Bypass OS security model
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # applicable to windows os only
  options.add_argument('start-maximized') # 
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://google.com/")
  print ("Headless Chrome Initialized on Windows OS")
  ```
- Effective [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) code block :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("--headless") # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # # Bypass OS security model
  options.add_argument('start-maximized')
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
  driver.get("http://google.com/")
  print ("Headless Chrome Initialized on Linux OS")
  ```

---

### Steps through YouTube Video

[How to initialize Chrome Browser in Maximized Mode through Selenium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pijKn8Sg8q0)

### Outro

[How to make firefox headless programmatically in Selenium with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python/46768243#46768243)

---

### tl; dr

Here is the link to the [**Sandbox**](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/design/sandbox.md) story.

Comment: One more edit needed here use `chrome_options=options` not `options=options`

Comment: Another one:
use `options.add_argument("--headless")` not `options.headless = True`

Comment: @DebanjanB, When I use your 13-Oct-18 code it executes, but throws the following errors: ` "Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead."` and `"Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it."` and `"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience...` for the website `https://test.plexonline.com` - browser with a 'head' executes with no errors though... any ideas?

Comment: @Python_Learner_DK The compete error stack trace may give us some clue. Can you raise a new question along with your binary versions please?

Comment: @DebanjanB, here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60058246/going-headless-in-selenium-with-chrome-using-python-executing-but-throwing-erro

Comment: @Jortega, chrome_options is depreciated so options=options is correct.

Answer (score 33):

## Update August 20, 2020 (still valid) -- Now is simple!

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.headless = True

self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            executable_path=DRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 16):

**UPDATED**
It works fine in my case:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
```

Just changed in 2020. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 6):

1. The .exe would be running anyway. According to Google - "Run in headless mode, i.e., without a UI or display server dependencies."
2. Better prepend 2 dashes to command line arguments, i.e. `options.add_argument('--headless')`
3. In headless mode, it is also suggested to disable the GPU, i.e. `options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')`

Answer (score 4):

Try using ChromeDriverManager

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.set_headless()
browser =webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get('https://google.com')
# capture the screen
browser.get_screenshot_as_file("capture.png")
```

Answer (score 3):

Solutions above don't work with websites with cloudflare protection, example: `https://paxful.com/fr/buy-bitcoin`.

Modify agent as follows:
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36")

Fix found here:
[What is the difference in accessing Cloudflare website using ChromeDriver/Chrome in normal/headless mode through Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59174899/what-is-the-difference-in-accessing-cloudflare-website-using-chromedriver-chrome)

Comment: I was working with pexels.com and came up with exactly this scenario. This works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
  
from chromedriver_py import binary_path
 
 
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1280x1696')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--v=99')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--single-process')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--data-path=/tmp/data-path')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--homedir=/tmp')
   chrome_options.add_argument('--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir')
   chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36')
   
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = binary_path,options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: These are the chrome options that are needed to set  in order to make chrome work in headless mode with the latest Chrome driver version 84

Answer (score 1):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
         "D:\\Lib\\chrome_driver_latest\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920x1080");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); 
chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, I faced an issue - a blank screen while using headless mode for Chrome with Selenium.

I tried overriding user-agent, but it didn't help. And then I saw in the documentation that for Chrome versions 109 and further it recommended setting headless mode the following way:

```
options.addArguments("--headless=new")
```

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chromium/ChromiumOptions.html#setHeadless(boolean)

So the full code to start headless mode is:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.addArguments("--headless=new") 
options.setExperimentalOption("w3c", false)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.example.com')
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since executable path is depricated

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chromeoptions=add_argument("--no-sandbox");
add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage'")
```

is not a supported browser

solution:

```
Open Browser    ${event_url}    ${BROWSER}   options=add_argument("--no-sandbox"); add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors"); add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage'")
```

don't forget to add spaces between `${BROWSER}`   options

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to hide the chromeDriver.exe window in alpha and beta versions of Selenium 4.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService # Similar thing for firefox also!
from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW # This flag will only be available in windows
chrome_service = ChromeService('chromedriver', creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service) # No longer console window opened, niether will chromedriver output
```

You can check it out from [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/8647). To pip install beta or alpha versions, you can do "pip install selenium==4.0.0.a7" or "pip install selenium==4.0.0.b4" (a7 means alpha-7 and b4 means beta-4 so for other versions you want, you can modify the command.) To import a specific version of a library in python you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445404/16333747).

Answer (score 0):

**RECENT UPDATE**

Recently there is an update performed on headless mode of Chrome. The flag `--headless` is now modified and can be used as below

For Chrome version 109 and above, `--headless=new` flag allows us to explore full functionality Chrome browser in headless mode.
For Chrome version 108 and below (till Version 96), `--headless=chrome` option will provide us the headless chrome browser.

So, let's add

```
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

for newer version of Chrome in headless mode as mentioned above.

The below works fine for me with Chrome version `110.0.5481.104`

```
chrome_driver_path = r"E:\driver\chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

//New Update
options.add_argument("--headless=new")  

options.binary_location = r"C:\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path, options=options)
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run Headless Chrome with [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) in Python as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657215/how-to-run-headless-chrome-with-selenium-in-python/76989689#76989689) explains it with Django examples and `--headless=new` is better because`--headless` uses old headless mode according [Headless is Going Away!](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/):

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new") # Here
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Or:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless=new") # Here
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Answer (score -3):

#### Update August 2021:

The fastest way to do is probably:

```
from selenium import webdriver  

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.set_headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

`options.headless = True` is deprecated.

Comment: didn't work for me. Needed go through `options.add_argument('headless')`

Comment: This is duplicates existing answers and is incorrect since `set_headless` is a method and is actually deprecated: `DeprecationWarning: use setter for headless property instead of set_headless` so should use `options.headless`