# ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)-Lost UI shared context : while initializing Chrome browser through ChromeDriver in Headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am getting this error when I attempt to run code on 2 of 3 computers:

```
[0502/155335.565:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.
```

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "\\chromedriver.exe"
print "chrome driver:" + chrome_driver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, 
executable_path=chrome_driver)

driver.get("http://www.google.com")

luck_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name=btnI")
luck_button.click()

driver.get_screenshot_as_file("capture.png")
```

Now I have checked all of the systems, they are running windows 10 64-bit, google chrome 64 bit Version: 66.0.3359.139, python 2.7 32-bit, chromedriver.exe 32-bit, pycharm 2018.1.1

funny thing is if I run this without the headless options then everything works. The browser pops up, the `I'm feeling lucky` button is pressed, and a screen shot is taken. Only if I add in the headless bit does this error occur.

I am not sure what could be different on 1 system that would allow this to work when the other systems are running the same software.

Answer (score 10):

When **Headless Chrome** was first released as **GA (General Availability)** by *Google Team* the article [**`Getting Started with Headless Chrome`**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) mentioned that :

```
--disable-gpu \                # Temporarily needed if running on Windows.
```

A note was added as :

> Right now, you'll also want to include the `--disable-gpu` flag if you're running on Windows.

As per the discussion [**`Headless: make --disable-gpu flag unnecessary`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737678) it was clear that :

> The `--disable-gpu` flag is no longer necessary on *Linux* or *Mac OSX*. It will also become unnecessary on Windows as soon as the bug [**`SwiftShader fails an assert on Windows in headless mode`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=729961) is fixed.

### What happened under the hood?

As per the discussion [**`headless: Switch from osmesa to SwiftShader`**](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/522068) as Google/Chromium team decided to ship **SwiftShader** with **Chrome** the team thought to start using it to render *GL content* in *Headless Mode*. This required a couple of changes as follows :

- Skip GPU data collection in *Headless Mode* since **SwiftShader** isn't considered a software implementation by that code which lead to a failure when we tried to retrieve information from the **Window System**.
- Only skip *GL initialization* in *InitializeStaticEGLInternal* if we intend to use **osmesa**. **SwiftShader** requires initialization like the other non-software implementations.
- **SwiftShader** is currently not supported on *Mac OSX*, so the team decided to continue to use the *physical GPU* in *Headless Mode* on that platform (unlike on other platforms where everything is software rendered).
- So, to disable **WebGL** support in *Headless Mode* they decided to use **--disable-gpu** and **--disable-software-rasterizer**

The idea to [**`Support WebGL in headless`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617551) is still under discussion but [**`SwiftShader fails an assert on Windows in headless mode`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=729961) with an error  as :

```
[0117/125830.649194:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1043)] Lost UI shared context.
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:37429/devtools/browser/1f0b2bf7-dfdd-44ac-9da7-f2659d352f0d
```

### Conclusion

This error doesn't impact your `@Test` and you can ignore the error for the time being.

Comment: We are using `ember exam` to run our tests and it stops completely because of this error. Is there any workaround to fix this

Comment: @xbmono Won't be able to comment on `ember exam` without the _relevant html_, _code trials_ and _error stack trace_. However as per the documentation from _Chromium Team_ the error **Lost UI shared context** looks harmless and is quite easily reproducible on _Windows10 OS_ which is not a **blocker** issue.

Comment: It may not be blocker in Win but we are using Debian and Jenkins Pipeline. All of our tests fail and stops because of this issue. We now have decided to temporarily disable tests which is not good

Comment: I have these settings: `module.exports = {
    "test_page": "tests/index.html?hidepassed",
    "disable_watching": true,
    "parallel": 6,
    "launch_in_ci": [
        "Chrome"
    ],
    "launch_in_dev": [
        "Chrome"
    ],
    "browser_start_timeout": 80,
    "browser_args": {
        "Chrome": [
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--disable-gpu',
                '--headless',
                '--window-size=1440,900'
            ]
    }
};
`

Comment: @xbmono As you are using **Debian**, `--disable-gpu` is not a desired parameter. See the discussion [Lost UI Shared Context Error - Running protractor tests in headless chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719963/lost-ui-shared-context-error-running-protractor-tests-in-headless-chrome)

Comment: I'm getting this without the --disable-gpu flag

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try adding these flags to Chrome driver options:

```
options.add_arguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
options.add_arguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
```

[See this link for more information.](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/33778/chromedriver-in-headless-mode-doesnt-work-correctly-because-of-windows-user-pol)