# How to set the name for screenshot.png with headless chrome screenshots?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using this command for screenshots:

```
chromium-browser --headless --screenshot https://www.google.com
```

From [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome).

This basically works:

```
[1101/145557.285618:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(980)] Lost UI shared context.
[1101/145558.357174:INFO:headless_shell.cc(538)] Written to file screenshot.png.
```

(It's [well covered elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143413/errorgpu-process-transport-factory-cc1007-lost-ui-shared-context-while-ini), but I haven't found a useful fix for the Lost UI error.  This is not relevant.)

How can I set the name of `screenshot.png` to be saved as something else?

I found a couple of rundowns of chrome command line switches, such as [this one](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), but the most likely looking flag, "--output" was not relevant to screenshots.

If you have a better recommendation for headless or chromeless screenshots, that is as simple as this, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`--screenshot=filename.png`.

Reference: https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=symbol:kDefaultScreenshotFileName

Similarly, `--print-to-pdf` also accepts a filename.