# Chrome Options in Python Selenium : Disable GPU vs Headless

Tags: python, selenium, chrome-options

In python-selenium chrome_options, What exactly is the difference between the following two options, I know both runs the selenium script without opening the browser.

```py
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657215/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome-webdriver

Comment: Personally, I have to use both in conjunction with each other for headless to work reliably.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You saw it right. Adding the argument **`--headless`** initiates the *Chrome Browsing Context* in **headless** mode.

However the purpose of the argument **`--disable-gpu`** was to enable [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) platform.  It was needed as [*SwiftShader fails an assert on Windows in headless mode*](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=729961) earlier.

This issue was **resolved** through [Headless: make --disable-gpu flag unnecessary](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737678)

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)-Lost UI shared context : while initializing Chrome browser through ChromeDriver in Headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143413/errorgpu-process-transport-factory-cc1007-lost-ui-shared-context-while-init/50148698#50148698)

Answer (score 7):

`--disable-gpu` *doesn't* run the script without opening the browser, only `--headless`. It used to be needed on Windows [Issue 737678: Headless: make --disable-gpu flag unnecessary](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737678), but this bug was fixed. `chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')` is all you need.