# Chrome works in headless mode on linux Server but shows "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist" error in gui mode through Selenium and Python

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, centos, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

selenium code to automate on chrome browser.

**chrome version**: 79.0.3945.117 (same for local and server machine)

**chrome driver**: tried all latest & below till chrome version driver.

**Execution Status - On Local machine:**
Works fine in headless and gui.

**Execution Status - On server Centros 7 machine.**
works fine in headless.In GUI giving error:

```
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
```

**Error log**

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
>>>>> Initializing the webdriver: CHROME on OS: linux64
Jan 11, 2020 12:27:52 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Starting ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614}) on port 16949
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
>>>>> Initializing the webdriver: CHROME on OS: linux64
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'qa9', ip: '', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_232'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x564eeb93d479 <unknown>

Jan 11, 2020 12:27:52 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
null
2020-01-11 12:27:52 INFO  BaseClass:23 - Test Completed
```

**Analysis**

1- Chrome is opening fine on server machine.

2- Using `google-chrome --no-sandbox` on server machine launches chrome

3- google-chrome is available at location /usr/bin/google-chrome

Hence tried all steps available at [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t/51510906#51510906) and using various chrome options but still unable to run selenium on chrome gui.

```
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); // Bypass OS security model
options.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome");
options.addArguments("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
options.addArguments("--test-type");
options.addArguments("--window-size=1420,1080");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); //to disable browser extension popup
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
```

**ChromeDriver logs**

```
[1578754796.203][INFO]: Launching chrome: /usr/bin/google-chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --log-level=0 --no-first-run --no-sandbox --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --start-maximized --test-type --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.CKtLXZ --window-size=1420,1080 data:,

(google-chrome:29029): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:59:56.269: cannot open display: 
[0111/155956.272402:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(311)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
[1578754796.304][INFO]: [e36d644ac30ae2e028b2ee00ba18b335] RESPONSE InitSession ERROR unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
[1578754796.304][DEBUG]: Log type 'driver' lost 0 entries on destruction
[1578754796.304][DEBUG]: Log type 'browser' lost 0 entries on destruction
```

Comment: Update the question with the complete error trace logs

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

---

You need to take care of a couple of things:

- The purpose of the argument `--disable-gpu` was to enable [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) platform.  It was needed as [*SwiftShader fails an assert on Windows in headless mode*](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=729961) earlier. This issue was **resolved** through [Headless: make --disable-gpu flag unnecessary](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737678). As you are on [centos](/questions/tagged/centos) you need to **remove** the line of code:

  ```
  options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
  ```
- As per your question as you are using *chrome=79.0* you need to ensure:

  - *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- As you are adding the *ExperimentalOption*:

  ```
  options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
  ```

  - You also need to add the *ExperimentalOption*:

    ```
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
    ```
  - But you need to remove:

    ```
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); //to disable browser extension popup
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Chrome Options in Python Selenium : Disable GPU vs Headless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047415/chrome-options-in-python-selenium-disable-gpu-vs-headless/59047724#59047724)
- [ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)-Lost UI shared context : while initializing Chrome browser through ChromeDriver in Headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143413/errorgpu-process-transport-factory-cc1007-lost-ui-shared-context-while-init/50148698#50148698)

Comment: I am using only "--no-sandbox" & "--disable-dev-shm-usage",  other arguments used in combinations but were not help.

Comment: @Vaibhav Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

An answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59781412/getting-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-unknown-error/59791405#59791405) indicts Chrome version > 78 as the cause.  Once we back-leveled, problem subsided:

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I installed the latest version of the "webdrivers" Rubygem (~> 4.2.0). Then, on my server, I ran:

```
whereis google-chrome
```

And got "/usr/bin/google-chrome"

I use ruby, and can now instantiate chrome with

```
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: ['headless'], binary: '/usr/bin/google-chrome')
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)
```