# Getting unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: linux, docker, selenium-chromedriver, testng, docker-container

Running TestNG scripts through docker container with standlone-chrome image, at the container level chrome fails to start in Linux machine.

capablities also includes : `--disable-dev-shm-usage",--no-sandbox,--headless.`

I tried updating the chrome driver but still didn't worked.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Answer (score 3):

StackOverflow newbie here.  Sharing the version of Chrome/ChromeDriver under discussion would help.  In any case, we back-leveled to Chrome 78 (+ Driver), and this problem went away.  It appears this error "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist" was introduced in late builds.

A few gotchas:

- Finding an older release may be problematic; we found them [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bugazelle/chromium-all-old-stable-versions/master/chromium.stable.json)  the version that worked for us is Linux_x64_693954_chrome-linux.zip
- The chrome-wrapper script should be renamed to google-chrome
- The chrome_sandbox executable must be renamed chrome-sandbox and chmodded 4755
- Install the matching Chromedriver version 78 (chromedriver_78.0.3904.105)