# Dusk with Selenium not working with Laradock

Tags: laravel, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-dusk, laradock

I'm running Dusk to test my Laravel application. I've recently switched to Laradock which took some time to set it all up as I have little experience with Docker, but it all seems to be working now. Except that Selenium doesn't seem to be working as it should.

I start and open my workspace like this:

```
sudo docker-compose up -d nginx postgres beanstalkd selenium
sudo docker-compose exec --user=laradock workspace bash
```

and then

```
php artisan dusk

1) Tests\Browser\SuccessLoginTest::test_user_can_login
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body textarea[name='email']"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=75.0.3770.90)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'f8c1169cd1a3', ip: '172.18.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.7-100.fc30.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I get a screenshot of the failing test showing the websiteand on it the and element it can't seem to find. Before I switched to Laradock everything was working properly, so the problems seems to be with Selenium. My setup looks like this and I use Laravel 5.7.28

```
protected function driver()
{
    $options = new ChromeOptions();

    $options->addArguments([
        '--headless',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--window-size=1920,1080',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors'
    ]);

    $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
    $capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);

    if (env('USE_SELENIUM', 'false') == 'true') {
        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub', $capabilities
        );
    } else {
        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:9515', $capabilities
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body textarea[name='email']"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=75.0.3770.90)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'f8c1169cd1a3', ip: '172.18.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.7-100.fc30.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the **NoSuchElementException** was raised during your program execution.

---

A bit of details about your *Test Configuration* interms of *chromedriver* **version** would have helped us to debug your issue in a better way. However you need to take care of a couple of things:

- The purpose of the argument `--disable-gpu` was to enable [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) platform.  It was needed as [*SwiftShader fails an assert on Windows in headless mode*](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=729961) earlier. This issue was **resolved** through [Headless: make --disable-gpu flag unnecessary](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737678). As you are on [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) / [laravel-dusk](/questions/tagged/laravel-dusk) / [laradock](/questions/tagged/laradock) on [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), you need to **remove** the line of code:

  ```
  '--disable-gpu' // applicable to windows os only
  ```
- As per your question as you are using *chrome=75.0*. you need to ensure:

  - *ChromeDriver* is updated to *ChromeDriver v75.0* as per the Release Notes of [*chromedriver=75.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/notes.txt)
- Having said that, ideally you need to ensure that:

  - *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
  - *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
  - *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
  - *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
  - *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
  - (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
  - (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
  - If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
  - Take a *System Reboot*.
  - Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
  - Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Chrome Options in Python Selenium : Disable GPU vs Headless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047415/chrome-options-in-python-selenium-disable-gpu-vs-headless/59047724#59047724)
- [ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)-Lost UI shared context : while initializing Chrome browser through ChromeDriver in Headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143413/errorgpu-process-transport-factory-cc1007-lost-ui-shared-context-while-init/50148698#50148698)

Comment: Hats off to your time and effort.Most people likely avoid such longer question and It seems you have all the time and answer whenever there is any problem related to selenium.Such a dedicated contributor  +1

Comment: Thanks indeed for the help so far. I'm not sure if I understand your remark 'A bit of details about your Test Configuration in terms of chromedriver version '. Isn't the error showing it is using 75.0.3770.90 ? As you state that there is a newer version I'm now trying to use v79. At the moment I did a pull on Laradock and are rebuilding. I will see if that is going to solve any issues.
I understand about the NoSuchElement error, but the problem is that the element is there. Somehow it is not found.

Comment: @Matthieu `headless chrome=75.0.3770.90` implies **chrome** _Browser_ version. Whereas `Driver info: driver.version: unknown` at some point **chromedriver** version was not detected.

Comment: Could that be a clue that it is unknown there? The Selenium Webdriver hub says it using chromedriverVersion": "75.0.3770.90. Seem to be stuck though on updatin to v79.

Comment: No, **75.0.3770.90** is the `chrome=75.0.3770.90` version and can't be the **chromedriver** version.