# The GPU process has crashed x time(s) error using ChromeDriver and Chrome in headless mode along with --disable-gpu and --user-data-dir arguments

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am using selenium to open a website. Specifically:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.html
```

But when it open it using **headless mode**, it displays following error:

```
[0513/155639.694:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1204)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:6573/devtools/browser/58f34b20-1a05-4bf0-8e64-1b5a5028b1f6
[0513/155639.710:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(21)] Unable to move the cache: Access is denied. (0x5)
[0513/155639.710:ERROR:cache_util.cc(138)] Unable to move cache folder C:/Users/Tazim Fatima/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data\Default\GPUCache to C:/Users/Tazim Fatima/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data\Default\old_GPUCache_000
[0513/155639.710:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
[0513/155639.710:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(606)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
[0513/155639.725:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1204)] The GPU process has crashed 2 time(s)
[0513/155639.725:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1204)] The GPU process has crashed 3 time(s)
[0513/155639.725:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1204)] The GPU process has crashed 4 time(s)
[0513/155639.725:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1204)] The GPU process has crashed 5 time(s)
[0513/155639.725:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1204)] The GPU process has crashed 6 time(s)
[0513/155639.725:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(153)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[0513/155642.754:ERROR:service_worker_storage.cc(1624)] Failed to delete the database: Database IO error`enter code here`
```

After lots of searching, i tried:

```
options.add_argument("--disable-user-media-security=true")
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")  
options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-software-rasterizer")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,1024")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--ignore-gpu-blacklist')
options.add_argument('--use-gl')
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.set_window_size(1200, 600)
driver.set_window_size(1280, 1024)
driver.get("https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.html")
```

Of course not all arguments at once but using different chunks at different times. Though one thing to note here is that when i use the argument **--no-sandbox**, The error changes to

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:1849/devtools/browser/426a187c-243f-42e3-a0b7-60c4f8dc73b2
[0513/163007.734:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3610)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: fail_if_major_perf_caveat + swiftshader
[0513/163007.742:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3610)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: fail_if_major_perf_caveat + swiftshader
[0513/163007.754:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3610)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: fail_if_major_perf_caveat + swiftshader
[0513/163007.758:INFO:CONSOLE(20)] "Initialization of backend webgl failed", source: https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.cb338cd2.js (20)
[0513/163007.758:INFO:CONSOLE(20)] "Error: WebGL is not supported on this device
    at new e (https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.cb338cd2.js:20:294522)
    at Object.factory (https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.cb338cd2.js:20:346621)
    at t.initializeBackend (https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.cb338cd2.js:20:43098)
    at t.initializeBackendsAndReturnBest (https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.cb338cd2.js:20:44537)
    at t.get [as backend] (https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.cb338cd2.js:20:41137)
    at t.makeTensor (https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.cb338cd2.js:20:48217)
    at Tn (https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.cb338cd2.js:20:81890)
    at Dn (https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.cb338cd2.js:20:81021)
    at o (https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.cb338cd2.js:20:491592)
    at Object.Pp [as decodeWeights] (https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.cb338cd2.js:20:491626)", source: https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.cb338cd2.js (20)
```

And it works. But compared to non headless mode, it is very very slow.

And i can't trade with speed. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
[0513/155639.710:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(21)] Unable to move the cache: Access is denied. (0x5)
[0513/155639.710:ERROR:cache_util.cc(138)] Unable to move cache folder C:/Users/Tazim Fatima/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data\Default\GPUCache to C:/Users/Tazim Fatima/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data\Default\old_GPUCache_000
[0513/155639.710:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
[0513/155639.710:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(606)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
[0513/155639.725:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1204)] The GPU process has crashed 2 time(s)
[0513/155639.725:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1204)] The GPU process has crashed 3 time(s)
[0513/155639.725:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1204)] The GPU process has crashed 4 time(s)
[0513/155639.725:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1204)] The GPU process has crashed 5 time(s)
[0513/155639.725:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1204)] The GPU process has crashed 6 time(s)
[0513/155639.725:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(153)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[0513/155642.754:ERROR:service_worker_storage.cc(1624)] Failed to delete the database: Database IO error
```

...implies that ChromeDriver/Chrome process was unable to move cache folder `..\Default\GPUCache` to `../AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data\Default\old_GPUCache_000`.

---

### Deep Dive

As per the article [Headless: make --disable-gpu flag unnecessary](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=737678) a lot of articles, documentation and guides recommended the usage of `--disable-gpu` flag as **`libosmesa.so`** wasn't present. With the availability of the merge [headless: Switch from osmesa to SwiftShader](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/522068/) this flag was no longer necessary on Linux or macOS. Moving forward with the availability of the merge [Always use SwiftShader for headless Chrome](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1161172) this flag was unnecessary on Windows even.

---

### Solution

As a solution you need to remove the following arguments:

- `--disable-gpu`
- `--disable-software-rasterizer`

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)-Lost UI shared context : while initializing Chrome browser through ChromeDriver in Headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143413/errorgpu-process-transport-factory-cc1007-lost-ui-shared-context-while-init/50148698#50148698).
- [Chrome Options in Python Selenium : Disable GPU vs Headless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047415/chrome-options-in-python-selenium-disable-gpu-vs-headless/59047724#59047724)

Additionally, when trying to access a specific *Chrome Profile* instead of mentioning the top `User Data` directory you need to go one step deeper and mention the *profile directory* e.g `../User Data/Profile 2` as follows:

```
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 2")
```

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to open a Chrome Profile through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195).
- [How to open a Chrome Profile through --user-data-dir argument of Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium/50637211#50637211)

Comment: Yes i have tried not using --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer. It dosent make a big difference and i have only single chrome profile. You stated that 'The idea to Support WebGL in headless is still under discussion'. And as far as i know, the website i am using, it is necessary to use WebGL. So the most i can do is trade with speed?

Comment: _the website i am using, it is necessary to use WebGL_: See the INFO log message: _[0513/163007.758:INFO:CONSOLE(20)] "Error: WebGL is not supported on this device_

Comment: without headless mode I CAN USE THE WEBSITE "WITHOUT ANY ERRORS"

Comment: @Coder7 Have you fixed this? I have the same issue. `--headless` option with `--user-data` is throwing that GPU error

Comment: I had to use `--no-sandbox` for it to work, the 2 options given here didn't work