# The GPU Process has crashed (123) times

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

So I wanted to store some cookie data to save for the next session, so I used this: `options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")`

However, When using that in headless mode, the chrome webdriver crashes with this error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55528/devtools/browser/df3970f2-e1b7-4b51-aabc-a3b0b2fda93e
[0209/121617.749:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1274)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
[0209/121617.749:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1274)] The GPU process has crashed 2 time(s)
[0209/121617.765:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1274)] The GPU process has crashed 3 time(s)
```

I've looked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61773844/the-gpu-process-has-crashed-x-times-error-using-chromedriver-and-chrome-in-hea) but found no help. Any suggestions?

BTW, I am using [This](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=88.0.4324.96/) webdriver (`chromedriver_win32.zip`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I was able to fix it. I believe the problem was that I was running it with elevated permissions. So I put the userdatadir to a location the user can access, and ran it with standard permissions, and it was fixed.