# I want to send whatsapp messages with selenium without opening a browser window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp

I want to automate whatsapp messages with selenium
But I do not want the browser window to show up

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure ChromeDriver to initiate Chrome browser in Headless mode through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug)

Comment: yes I found that am not able to that :(