# Can't get Chromium browser to run headless Pi OS

Tags: python, selenium, chromium, headless, raspberry-pi4

I've got a Pi4 and using the latest Pi OS
I'm trying to take a screenshot of a Chromium webpage (weather map) with Selenium while displaying weather forescast program with Pygame and it works perfectly
The only issue is that it "sometimes" causes Pygame to toggle out of fullscreen and not go back to fullscreen after saving the image
This only happens sometimes and not all the time

I think the problem could be solved by using Chromium headless but I cannot get this to work
Anyone able to help?

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    from PIL import Image
    import pygame
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
    url = "https://www.windy.com/screenshot?53.199,-2.000,7,i:pressure"
    driver.get(url)
    driver.fullscreen_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.save_screenshot('weather.png')
    basewidth = 240
    img = Image.open('weather.png')
    driver.quit()
    wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
    img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save('/home/pi/images/weather_icons/kia.png')
```

If I use
`driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver') --headless`
it says

```py
  File "map.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver') --headless
  NameError: name 'headless' is not defined
```

I have Firefox-esr installed as well but could not get this working and as chromium browser is working I'd like to stick with this "if possible"

Comment: any error message in particular that you could share? also i may be wrong, but i don't think you can do a screenshot of headless

Comment: @kevinnls screenshot in headless mode does work. It might be required to have all of the necessary libraries installed on the system so that you would be able to render the image if not running in headless mode.

Comment: i stand corrected. thank you @Z4-tier. OP, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929945/13982210) help?

Comment: Many thanks
This made it work :)

`options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver', options=options)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure ChromeDriver to initiate Chrome browser in Headless mode through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug)