# How do I get Selenium to open Chrome in headless mode on Windows?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here's the code I'm using. The program runs fine, but it opens an instance of Chrome instead of opening it in headless mode, even though I set it to headless. What's wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver_service = Service("drivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: `webdriver.chrome(options=chrome_options, ...)`

Comment: Hi, the community already has a answer to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug/49582462

Comment: Thank you very much :)