# Selenium keeps opening "data;." tab when I want it to be headless

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I created a bot to scan usernames and pull up people's stats in the game Warzone, but I am having a problem, every time I run my code everything works but it keeps opening that "data;." tab of chrome and I don't want it to open anything. How do I fix this? I think I got myself into a deep hole of not understanding this whole chromedriver side of Selenium and I probably have more stuff on my code causing this that I don't need. Below is the part of my code running the Selenium tasks. Like I said, everything works fine but I hate how it opens a chrome tab every time I run the code and I have to manually close it. Thank you!

```
from pathlib import Path

from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Text, Button, PhotoImage
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import pyautogui
import time
import cv2
from pytesseract import *
from PIL import Image
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
ser = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import mss
import mss.tools

pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'...tesseract.exe'

OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path("./assets")

def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry("431x550")
    window.configure(bg = "#ECECEC")
    window.title("BOT")
    window.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
    
    def webscrape(username, original):
        t = time.time()
    
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.headless = True
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get(f'https://cod.tracker.gg/warzone/profile/atvi/{username}/overview')
        page_title = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lead')
        
        if not page_title or page_title[0] == "WARZONE STATS NOT FOUND":
            print("WARZONE STATS NOT FOUND - Private profile")
            usernameBox.delete(0, tk.END)
            usernameBox.insert(0, "WARZONE STATS NOT FOUND - Private profile")
        
        else:
            usernameBox.delete(0, tk.END)
            usernameBox.insert(0, original)
            search = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'value')
            
            if len(search) > 4:
                print("Wins:", search[0].text)
                winsBox.delete(0, tk.END)
                winsBox.insert(0, search[0].text)
                
                print("Win %:", search[1].text)
                winPercentageBox.delete(0, tk.END)
                winPercentageBox.insert(0, search[1].text)
                
                print("Kills:", search[2].text)
                killsBox.delete(0, tk.END)
                killsBox.insert(0, search[2].text)
                
                print("K/D:", search[3].text)
                KDBox.delete(0, tk.END)
                KDBox.insert(0, search[3].text)
    
                print("Score/min:", search[4].text)
                scoreMinBox.delete(0, tk.END)
                scoreMinBox.insert(0, search[4].text)
                
            else:
                print("Incorrect name or private profile")
                
                usernameBox.delete(0, tk.END)
                usernameBox.insert(0, original)
                
                winsBox.delete(0, tk.END)
                winsBox.insert(0, "-----")
                
                winPercentageBox.delete(0, tk.END)
                winPercentageBox.insert(0, "-----")
                
                killsBox.delete(0, tk.END)
                killsBox.insert(0, "-----")
                
                KDBox.delete(0, tk.END)
                KDBox.insert(0, "-----")
                
                scoreMinBox.delete(0, tk.END)
                scoreMinBox.insert(0, "-----")
                
        elapsed = time.time() - t
        print(elapsed, "Time to webscrape")
        webscrapeBox.delete(0, tk.END)
        webscrapeBox.insert(0, str(round(elapsed, 2)) + " seconds")
        
        driver.close()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug/49582462 have you tried this?

Comment: Kind of, what I have is what the last comment suggests, the "August 2021" update

Answer (score 0):

Replace `options.headless = True` with `options.add_argument('--headless')`.

Comment: Did not work unfortunately