# Issue with Chronium and snap when trying to use Selenium webdriver (v 4.10.0)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, snap

I am trying to scrape a website using Selenium but I am having some issues either with Chromium or the path to the chromedriver. I am a beginner with Selenium but can't seem to find the solution.

I am working on WSL with Ubuntu in a local pyenv.
So I have moved both the Linux and Windows chromedriver to

```
driver_path_windows = "/home/leah/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/envs/vinted-api/bin/chromedriver.exe"
driver_path_linux = "/home/leah/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/envs/vinted-api/bin/chromedriver"
```

And have tried both

```
service = Service(driver_path_windows)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

AND

```
service = Service(driver_path_linux)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

Neither of these work, and I get this error message
"message": "Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.\n  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)\n  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.

I have also tried with paths in both my desktop for the .exe or just in a standard WSL directory and  I get the same error, which makes me think that there is an error with chromium.

When I run `snap install chromium` I get this error:

```
✗ chromium-browser --version                                                

Command '/usr/bin/chromium-browser' requires the chromium snap to be installed.
Please install it with:

snap install chromium

✗ snap install chromium 
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/chromium: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

And this is the output for `snap version`

```
snap    2.54.3+20.04.1ubuntu0.2
snapd   unavailable
series  -
```

But I don't have any error entry logs

```
journalctl -u snapd                                                     
No journal files were found.
-- No entries --
```

I can run `sudo apt install chromium-browser`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
chromium-browser is already the newest version (1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 245 not upgraded.
```

But not  `sudo snap install chromium`

```
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/chromium: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

I have also tried to download the official Ubuntu version for Chrome, based on this solution (option 1), [Unable to install chromium using snap on WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71719633/unable-to-install-chromium-using-snap-on-wsl?rq=2)

But I am not sure how to get Chrome to run from the WSL