# web scraping RSelenium findElement

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium, findelement

I feel this is supposed to be simple but I have been struggled to get it right. I'm trying to extract the Employees number ("2,300,000") from this webpage: https://fortune.com/company/walmart/

I used Chrome's extension SelectorGadget to locate the number---"info__row--7f9lE:nth-child(13) .info__value--2AHH7""

````
```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(netstat)

rs_driver_object<-rsDriver(browser='chrome',chromever='103.0.5060.53',verbose=FALSE, port=free_port())
remDr<-rs_driver_object$client
remDr$navigate('https://fortune.com/company/walmart/')
Employees<-remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath','//h3[@class="info__row--7f9lE:nth-child(13) .info__value--2AHH7"]')
Employees
```

An error says 

> "Selenium message:no such element: Unable to locate element".

I have also tried:
```
Employees<-remDr$findElement(using = 'class name','info__value--2AHH7')
```
But it returns the data not as wanted. 


Can someone point out the problem? Really appreciate it!
````

**Updated**
I modified the code as suggested by Frodo below in the comment to apply to multiple webpages to save the statistics as a dataframe. But I still encountered an error.

```
    library(RSelenium)
    library(rvest)
    library(netstat)
    
rs_driver_object<-rsDriver(browser='chrome',chromever='103.0.5060.53',verbose=FALSE, port=netstat::free_port())
remDr<-rs_driver_object$client


Data<-data.frame("url" = c("https://fortune.com/company/walmart/", "https://fortune.com/company/amazon-com/"              
                           ,"https://fortune.com/company/apple/"                   
                           ,"https://fortune.com/company/cvs-health/" 
                           ,"https://fortune.com/company/jpmorgan-chase/"          
                           ,"https://fortune.com/company/verizon/"                 
                           ,"https://fortune.com/company/ford-motor/"              
                           , "https://fortune.com/company/general-motors/"          
                           ,"https://fortune.com/company/anthem/"                  
                           , "https://fortune.com/company/centene/"                 
                           ,"https://fortune.com/company/fannie-mae/"              
                           , "https://fortune.com/company/comcast/"                 
                           , "https://fortune.com/company/chevron/"                 
                           ,"https://fortune.com/company/dell-technologies/"       
                           ,"https://fortune.com/company/bank-of-america-corp/"    
                           ,"https://fortune.com/company/target/") )

Data$numEmp<-"NA"
Data$numEmp <- numeric()



for (i in 1:length(Data$url))
  {
  
remDr$navigate(url = Data$url[i])
pgSrc <- remDr$getPageSource()
pgCnt <- read_html(pgSrc[[1]])
Data$numEmp[i] <- pgCnt %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//div[text()='Employees']/following-sibling::div") %>%
  html_text(trim = TRUE)

}
Data$numEmp
```

> Selenium message:unknown error: unexpected command response
> (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)
> Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
> System info: host: 'DESKTOP-VCCIL8P', ip: '192.168.1.249', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_311'
> Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
Further Details: run errorDetails method

Can someone please take another look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `RSelenium` to load up the webpage and get the page source

```
remdr$navigate(url = 'https://fortune.com/company/walmart/')
pgSrc <- remdr$getPageSource()
```

Use `Rvest` to read the contents of the webpage

```
pgCnt <- read_html(pgSrc[[1]])
```

Further, use `rvest::html_nodes` and `rvest::html_text` functions to extract the text using relevant `xpath` selectors. (this [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ruto-xpath-finder/ilcoelkkcokgeeijnopjnolmmighnppp) should help)

```
reqTxt <- pgCnt %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//div[text()='Employees']/following-sibling::div") %>%
  html_text(trim = TRUE)
```

Output of `reqTxt`

```
> reqTxt
[1] "2,300,000"
```

### UPDATE

The error `Selenium message:unknown error: unexpected command response`  seems to be occurring specifically 103 version of Chromedriver. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72758996/selenium-seleniumwire-unknown-error-cannot-determine-loading-status-from-unkn). One of the answers there was a giving a simple wait of 5 seconds before and after the driver navigates to the URL. And I have also used `tryCatch` to keep continuing the code to run within a while loop. Essentially, the code will run until it loads the page. This seems to work.

```
# Function to fetch employee count
getEmployees <- function(myURL) {
  pagestatus <<- 0
  while(pagestatus == 0) {
    tryCatch(
      expr = remDr$navigate(url = myURL),
      pagestatus <<- 1,
      error = function(error){
        pagestatus <<- 0
        
      }  
    )
  }
  pgSrc <- remDr$getPageSource()
  pgCnt <- read_html(pgSrc[[1]])
  return(pgCnt %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//div[text()='Employees']/following-sibling::div") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE))
}
```

Implement this function to all of your dataframe URLs.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Data)) {
  Sys.sleep(5)
  Data[i, 2] <- getEmployees(Data[i, 1])
  Sys.sleep(5)
}
```

Now when we see the output of second column

```
> Data[, 2]
 [1] "2,300,000" "1,608,000" "154,000"   "258,000"   "271,025"   "118,400"  
 [7] "183,000"   "157,000"   "98,200"    "72,500"    "7,400"     "189,000"  
[13] "42,595"    "133,000"   "208,248"   "450,000"
```

Comment: Thanks, Frodo. I was modifying your code to apply for scraping multiple webpages. But I'm quite new to Loop function. Could you please take another look at my code? I updated it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be with RSelenium only? In my experience, the most flexible approach is to use RSelenium to navigate to the required pages (where findElement helps you find boxes to enter text into or buttons to click) and then use rvest to extract what you need from the page.

Start with

```
rs_driver_object<-rsDriver(browser='chrome',chromever='103.0.5060.53',verbose=FALSE, port=netstat::free_port())
remDr<-rs_driver_object$client
remDr$navigate('https://fortune.com/company/walmart/')
page_source <- remDr$getPageSource()
pg <- xml2::read_html(page_source[[1]])
```

How you then go about it depends on how specific you want the solution to be wrt this exact page. Here is one way:

```
rvest::html_elements(pg, "div.info__row--7f9lE") |> 
  rvest::html_text2()
```

or

```
rvest::html_elements(pg, "div:nth-child(13) > div.info__value--2AHH7") |> 
  rvest::html_text2()
```

or

```
rvest::html_elements(pg, "div.info__row--7f9lE")[11] |> 
  rvest::html_children()
```

or

```
rvest::html_elements(pg, '.info__row--7f9lE:nth-child(13) .info__value--2AHH7') |> 
  rvest::html_text2()
```

et cetera. What you do in the rvest part would depend on how general you want the selection/extraction process to be.