# Can't `pip3 install -r requirement.txt`

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'm getting dependency error while installing dependency for django project

Here is my part of requirement file

```
social-auth-app-django==1.2.0
social-auth-core==1.7.0
...
stream-django==1.4.0
..
PyJWT==1.3.0
..
```

without pyJWT == 1.3.0 line,

> stream-python 2.8.1 has requirement pyjwt==1.3.0, but you'll have pyjwt 1.6.4 which is incompatible.

with pyJWT == 1.3.0

> social-auth-core 1.7.0 has requirement PyJWT>=1.4.0, but you'll have pyjwt 1.3.0 which is incompatible.
>   djangorestframework-jwt 1.11.0 has requirement PyJWT<2.0.0,>=1.5.2, but you'll have pyjwt 1.3.0 which is incompatible.

requirements.txt. <- I deleted many lines from here. It works on my ubuntu machine but somehow most of packages are deprecated since last year.

```
apturl==0.5.2
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
bleach==1.5.0
blinker==1.3
boto==2.48.0
Brlapi==0.6.4
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
checkbox-support==0.22
command-not-found==0.3
cryptography==1.2.3
decorator==4.0.10
defer==1.0.6
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==1.10.5
django-allauth==0.32.0
django-braces==1.11.0
django-cors-headers==2.1.0
django-cors-middleware==1.3.1
django-crispy-forms==1.6.0
django-filter==1.1.0
django-markdown-deux==1.0.5
django-multiselectfield==0.1.8
django-oauth-toolkit==1.0.0
django-pagedown==0.1.1
django-rest-auth==0.9.1
django-rest-framework-social-oauth2==1.0.8
django-storages==1.6.5
django-storages-redux==1.3.3
djangorestframework==3.6.3
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
entrypoints==0.2.2
feedparser==5.1.3
guacamole==0.9.2
hmmlearn==0.2.0
html5lib==0.999
httplib2==0.9.1
httpsig==1.1.2
idna==2.6
ipykernel==4.5.2
ipython==5.1.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
ipywidgets==5.2.2
Jinja2==2.8
jsonschema==2.5.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==4.4.0
jupyter-console==5.0.0
jupyter-core==4.2.1
language-selector==0.1
louis==2.6.4
lxml==3.5.0
Mako==1.0.3
Markdown==2.6.9
markdown2==2.3.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
mistune==0.7.3
nbconvert==5.0.0
nbformat==4.2.0
notebook==4.3.0
numpy==1.12.1
oauthlib==2.0.3
onboard==1.2.0
padme==1.1.1
pandocfilters==1.4.1
pexpect==4.0.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
Pillow==3.1.0
plainbox==0.25
prompt-toolkit==1.0.9
psycopg2==2.6.2
ptyprocess==0.5
pyasn1==0.1.9
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycups==1.9.73
pycurl==7.43.0
Pygments==2.1.3
pygobject==3.20.0
PyJWT==1.3.0
pyparsing==2.0.3
python-apt==1.1.0b1
python-debian==0.1.27
python-systemd==231
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2017.3
pyxdg==0.25
pyzmq==16.0.2
qtconsole==4.2.1
reportlab==3.3.0
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
scikit-learn==0.18.1
screen-resolution-extra==0.0.0
sessioninstaller==0.0.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.10.0
sklearn==0.0
social-auth-app-django==1.2.0
social-auth-core==1.4.0
stream-django==1.3.3
stream-python==2.5.0
system-service==0.3
terminado==0.6
testpath==0.3
tornado==4.4.2
traitlets==4.3.1
ubuntu-drivers-common==0.0.0
ufw==0.35
unattended-upgrades==0.1
unity-scope-calculator==0.1
unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks==0.1
unity-scope-colourlovers==0.1
unity-scope-devhelp==0.1
unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks==0.1
unity-scope-gdrive==0.7
unity-scope-manpages==0.1
unity-scope-openclipart==0.1
unity-scope-texdoc==0.1
unity-scope-tomboy==0.1
unity-scope-virtualbox==0.1
unity-scope-yelp==0.1
unity-scope-zotero==0.1
urllib3==1.22
usb-creator==0.3.0
virtualenv==15.1.0
wcwidth==0.1.7
widgetsnbextension==1.2.6
xdiagnose==3.8.4.1
xkit==0.0.0
XlsxWriter==0.7.3
```

Comment: Welcome to dependency hell, Can you upgrade to pyJWT 1.5, e.g. `pyJWT==1.5.2`?

Comment: I just got this error from pyJWT = 1.5.0 `djangorestframework-jwt 1.11.0 has requirement PyJWT<2.0.0,>=1.5.2, but you'll have pyjwt 1.5.0 which is incompatible.
stream-python 2.8.1 has requirement pyjwt==1.3.0, but you'll have pyjwt 1.5.0 which is incompatible.`

Comment: You can do something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445167/force-python-to-use-an-older-version-of-module-than-what-i-have-installed-now

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis thanks for a help but I would not want to change my code :(

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis but you got my point. It worked on my ubuntu before

Comment: are you in a virtual environment??

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis YES! What's wrong with it???

Comment: No, I worried about the opposite :P

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis ohnn.... any guess..??? I can't believe it worked on ubuntu and doesn't work on my mac

Comment: Are using the same python version and revision ?

Comment: Both from virtualenv and local print same versions which are `Python 2.7.10` `Python 3.6.5`

Comment: It's odd that it worked on Ubuntu, it shouldn't have. Are you sure the requirements file matches what you've had there? Try running `pip freeze` from the virtualenv where you had the packages installed. You can also try creating a new virtualenv on Ubuntu and installing from requirements.txt.

Comment: @Norrius The problem is the desktop is no longer with me :( I can pick it up in three months.