# Is there any tool to run the specific packages for each python file, instead of creating multiple virtual environments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having multiple python files each python file will take the different versions of pandas and different python versions. Currently, I am using virtual environments to run the python script. Is there any tool or module that took the requirements file contains module name including the version and will the python file with that requirements.

Comment: What's wrong with having multiple virtual environments?

Comment: @Thomas there is no problem with creating the environments, But even for a single change, we will be creating the separate environments, ex: one environment is having pandas 0.1.1 and another environment is having pandas 0.1.2, only for this pandas version change we are creating separate environments.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445167/force-python-to-use-an-older-version-of-module-than-what-i-have-installed-now.