# Using multiple versions of one package

Tags: python, installation, pip, easy-install, pkg-resources

I recently tried to install [neuralcoref](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref) to use with the NLP package [spaCy](https://spacy.io/universe/project/neuralcoref). The problem is that neuralcoref only works with spaCy versions **>=2.1.0** and **<2.2.0**. My current version is way above that and includes features I wouldn't want to sacrifice.

So, my question is, can I install an older version of spaCy **in addition** to the existing one, so as to only use it with neuralcoref? The answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445167/force-python-to-use-an-older-version-of-module-than-what-i-have-installed-now) seems to suggest it is possible to navigate among multiple version options when importing, but I don't understand exactly how. Could I perhaps install the package under a different name?

**UPDATE:**
I think I managed to install another version using `easy_install spacy==2.1.0`, now the `\site-packages` dir contains both the original `\spacy` folder as well as a folder named `\spacy-2.1.0-py3.7-win-amd64.egg`, and within it are another two: `\spacy` and `\EGG-INFO`.

Still, when I do a `pip freeze`, '`spacy=2.1.0`' doesn't show up, nor does `pkg_resoucrces.require('spacy==2.1.0')` work when importing, outputting a `VersionConflict` error instead.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41573588/6692898

Comment: Use virtual environment when you have version conflicts for a particular package. It is anyways recommended.