# how to import a torch 1.7.1 when torch 1.4.0 is also installed

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

how to import a torch 1.7.1 when torch 1.4.0 is also installed

When I run the command: ! pip list
It lists all libraries with : torch    1.7.1

Now when I run:

```
>>>import torch
>>>torch.__version__
'1.4.0'
```

How Do I import torch==1.7.1 in the python program?
I am using python 3.8.3 and windows 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force python to use an older version of module (than what I have installed now)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445167/force-python-to-use-an-older-version-of-module-than-what-i-have-installed-now)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different way to answer your question, but if you want to have two versions of `torch` installed simultaneously for different purposes (e.g. running different programs), my recommendation would be to use `torch 1.7.1` and `torch 1.4.1` in separate **virtual environments**.  Please see the links below for guides on getting started with these:

1. [`virtualenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html):

```
# Create virtual environment
python3 -m venv torch-env

# Activate virtual environment
torch-env\Scripts\activate.bat

# Any packages you install now are ONLY for this virtual environment
pip install torch==1.7.1  # Or 1.4.1 in a separate environment
```

2. [`conda`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html):

```
# Create virtual environment with Python 3.8.3
conda create --name torch-env python=3.8.3

# Activate virtual environment
conda activate torch-env

# Install torch
pip install torch==1.7.1  # Or 1.4.1
```

Creating separate virtual environments will allow you to have multiple versions of `torch` simultaneously without any issues.  You should then be able to import as you do above and use them interchangeably simply by switching environments.

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one version of a package installed you can use package resources as follows

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require("torch==1.7.1")
import torch
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445167/force-python-to-use-an-older-version-of-module-than-what-i-have-installed-now)