# How to only install (or import) a specific version of discord.py?

Tags: python, pip, discord.py

I'm trying to install the discord-1.7.3 package. pip installs discord-1.7.3 **and** discord.py-2.0.1. My program is incompatible with version 2.x.x so I need only version 1.7.3 to install. [The answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5226311/331024) suggest telling pip what version to install, but this doesn't work:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.2
$ pip install 'discord==1.7.3'
Collecting discord==1.7.3
  Using cached discord-1.7.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 kB)
Collecting discord.py>=1.7.3
  Using cached discord.py-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4 in /home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from discord.py>=1.7.3->discord==1.7.3) (3.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in /home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord==1.7.3) (6.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord==1.7.3) (22.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3 in /home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord==1.7.3) (4.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3.0,>=2.0 in /home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord==1.7.3) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: aiosignal>=1.1.2 in /home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord==1.7.3) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in /home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord==1.7.3) (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: frozenlist>=1.1.1 in /home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord==1.7.3) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in /home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord==1.7.3) (3.3)
Installing collected packages: discord.py, discord
Successfully installed discord-1.7.3 discord.py-2.0.1
```

... you see discord.py-2.0.1 was installed anyway.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445404/331024) suggests using pkg_resources to control what version is imported, but that doesn't work either:

```
$ cat test.py
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require("discord==1.7.3")
import discord

print(discord.version_info)

$ python3 test.py
VersionInfo(major=2, minor=0, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How to only install (or import) a specific package version?" is the wrong question in this case.

You [don't want to install the `discord` package](https://pypi.org/project/discord/) at all, since it's just a mirror/placeholder.

> **This is a mirror package!**
> It is recommended to install discord.py instead.

If you want version 1.7.3 of [Discord.py](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/), then install the correct package:

```
pip install discord.py==1.7.3
```

In fact, the `discord` placeholder package doesn't even contain any code:

```
$ unzip -l discord-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Archive:  discord-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      381  08-20-2022 23:51   discord-2.0.0.dist-info/METADATA
       92  08-20-2022 23:51   discord-2.0.0.dist-info/WHEEL
        1  08-20-2022 23:51   discord-2.0.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
      296  08-20-2022 23:51   discord-2.0.0.dist-info/RECORD
```

All it does is require `discord.py>=2.0.0`:

```
$ unzip -p discord-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl discord-2.0.0.dist-info/METADATA
Metadata-Version: 2.1
Name: discord
Version: 2.0.0
Summary: A mirror package for discord.py. Please install that instead.
Home-page: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
Author: Rapptz
License: UNKNOWN
Platform: UNKNOWN
Description-Content-Type: text/markdown
Requires-Dist: discord.py (>=2.0.0)
```

Comment: Thank you! ``$pip install discord.py==1.7.3`` did the trick. Perhaps include this command in your answer for future reference?

Comment: @x-x Sure, did that.